# Codeigniter insert_batch is not working

Tags: html, codeigniter

why insert_batch query does not work ? where is the wrong? here is my html and php codes. I am not sure why do not works. thank you for help from now.

html

```
<input name="urun_id[]" />
<input name="cins[]" />
<input name="miktar[]" />
<input name="birim_fiyat[]" />

<input name="urun_id[]" />
<input name="cins[]" />
<input name="miktar[]" />
<input name="birim_fiyat[]" />
```

php;

```
 $urun_id =  json_decode($this->input->post("urun_id"), true);
  $cins =  json_decode($this->input->post("cins"), true);
  $miktar =  json_decode($this->input->post("miktar"), true);
  $birim_fiyat =  json_decode($this->input->post("birim_fiyat"), true); 

$udata = array();
 foreach ($urun_id  as $u) { 
 $udata[] = array("urun_id"=> $u["value"]);
       }

       $mdata = array();
 foreach ($miktar  as $m) {
       $mdata[] = array("miktar"=>$m["value"]);
  }
$a = array($udata, $mdata);
 $this->db->insert_batch('urunteklif', $a);
```

Comment: Any errors in your PHP log?

Comment: return just null, it does not give any error. when i add seperate it works. but the query is one but foreach loop is seperate.

Comment: mh i'm wondering how the hack should that work ? basically you pass an array with 2 arrays with different field names...

Comment: the post values all are array

Comment: i edited the question.

Comment: Please don't use question titles such as "why does this not work", "why does my code not work". Explain in the tilte what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

you've to group your data

something like the following should work

```
<input name="group[0][urun_id]" />
<input name="group[0][cins]" />
<input name="group[0][miktar]" />
<input name="group[0][birim_fiyat]" />

<input name="group[1][urun_id]" />
<input name="group[1][cins]" />
<input name="group[1][miktar]" />
<input name="group[1][birim_fiyat]" />
```

i'm not sure why you want to `json_decode` the data here you (you've to show why you are doing this)

but in the end in your controller - the only line you really need is

```
$this->db->insert_batch('urunteklif', $this->input->post('group');
```

Comment: you've to dude - otherwise you can't assign the right values to the right group, maybe you show a little bit more from your code - because what you've shown so far isn't helping at all - the only thing i'm certain is - that you've to group your data properly...